# How to store/deal with data available to other classes in c#

Tags: c#, class, static

I'm writing a CAD program. Let's say I have in input class, this class reads various data from a text file and creates lots of lists/dictionaries and .... These data need to be accessed by other methods in other classes to be modified. Now here is how I have done it so far:

I have one static class: `Building.cs` When I create/or load a project this class holds all the data like list of columns, beams, points, etc. All of these are stored as private fields. I can access these using the class's public methods like GetColumns or GetPoints ...

Now I also have non-static classes. They contain 2-3 public methods. and do some stuff on various parts of the building.

```
public static class Building
{
    private static List<Column> columns;
    private static List<Beams> beams;
    private static List<Points> points;

    public static List<Column> GetColumns() 
    {
        return Columns;
    }
}

public class ColumnsService()
{
    private List<Columns> columns;
    public GroupColumns(List<Columns> columns)
    {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public void Group()
    {
        // group columns
    }
}

var columns = Building.GetColumns();
var columnsService = new ColumnsService(columns);
columnsService.Group();
```

I was wondering is this the way to go? How else can I store the data. The data needs to be accessible throughout the lifetime of the program to most of the classes. What are the best practices.

Comment: Just make them public. No point in bothering with additional get methods. If you don't want it changed outside the class make them properties and make the `set` private.

Comment: I'm afraid it's kind of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: Having a single static catch-all place for values is essentially just putting everything in global scope.  Not really ideal.  As for how to access them, it sounds like that's already working.  If the data truly *should be* static (I don't know enough about the project to be certain) then a static member with a getter is exactly how that would be done.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a god object - it's simply a model object, and is only doing what it should - load the data and store it. According to the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle you want to encapsulate the whole responsibility into a single class, the question is how you categorize that responsibility. To be frank  what Vahid is doing is pretty much doing this already.

David, he also said that he uses this data with most of his classes, which would place the data into global scope anyway. But should make sure to handle them as properties with private set.

Comment: @Dracor: `"which would place the data into global scope anyway"` - Not necessarily.  Again, we'd need to know more about the design.  But just because two things need to access the same resource doesn't mean that resource should just be global.  A `Building` sounds like an instance model, not just a collection of data.  Something with attributes and operations specific to, well, a building.  Something like a `BuildingFactory` with a static factory method sounds more appropriate, or perhaps a `BuildingRepository`.

Comment: @David The Building class is just to store the data. I don't know any other way to persist the data to be accessed by other classes throughout the program. One the other hand, everyone says that I should avoid static/global variable. Is there any other choice left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What, semantically, is a `Building`?

To me, the name implies that it's an instance of a structure.  That, in the overall business domain, there can be many "buildings" and at any given moment one is interacting with one of them.

If that's the case, then it seems unintuitive to me to make it `static`.  If there's more than one, it should be an instance model.  It would contain attributes which describe it and operations which interact with it.  The business domain being modeled should drive the structure of this object before any consideration is given to how other objects are going to interact with it.

So let's assume we make it an instance model:

```
public class Building
{
    // attributes and operations
}
```

Then, as you ask, how do other objects interact with it?

Depends on the interactions.

Let's say an object needs to "render" a building in some way.  Let's call it `BuildingPrinter` for lack of a better term.  Clearly it needs a `Building` to "print".  So it requires one for that operation:

```
public class BuildingPrinter
{
    public void Print(Building building)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you have an object which "wraps" a building in some way.  Something which can't meaningfully exist without a building, regardless of the operations performed.  I can't think of one for that particular business domain, so let's just call it a `BuildingWidget`.  Since it needs a building to exist at all, it requires one:

```
public class BuildingWidget
{
    private Building currentBuilding;

    private BuildingWidget() { }

    public BuildingWidget(Building building)
    {
        currentBuilding = building;
    }
}
```

The point is, from the perspective of the models which construct the overall domain, if something is required then it must be supplied.  The models shouldn't go out to some global data store, tightly coupling with that data store, to get what they need.  This is called the Dependency Inversion Principle.

But where will the *consuming code* which orchestrates the interactions of these models get instances of a `Building`?  There are a number of potential solutions to that.

Two common patterns would be to have a static factory or a repository.  For example:

```
public class BuildingFactory
{
    public static Building FetchBuilding(int buildingId)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

This factory might have a static *cached* building object.  The building itself isn't static, but for performance reasons an instance of it is cached statically so that it's not constantly re-fetched from a backing data store (such as a database).  You might also add methods to invalidate the cache and re-fetch, or encapsulate that logic into the factory itself (such as always re-fetch after 5 minutes or after 10 accesses or some other rule).  (Behind the scenes, this factory might even use a repository, shown below, to re-fetch that instance.  In which case, you guessed it, a `BuildingRepository` would be required on the `BuildingFactory` constructor.)

This factory object may also be responsible for *creating* a building based on some specifications, if for example you have reason to make the `Building` constructor private.

Or, to re-fetch from data, consider a repository:

```
public class BuildingRepository
{
    public Building GetBuilding(int buildingId)
    {
        // fetch from database
    }

    public Building SaveBuilding(Building building)
    {
        // save to database, return updated version
    }
}
```

Then other code throughout the domain, including the consuming code, can use these objects to get/save buildings.  The factory is static, so that can be invoked anywhere.  The repository is instance but doesn't need to be globally distinct, so that can be instantiated anywhere (or pulled form a dependency injection container).

Comment: Brilliant architecture!

Comment: I only need one Building for the lifetime of the program. I won't need other instances of it. Basically, this is what I'm doing. I'm reading data from a text file, and updating the fields/properties of the static Building class. This class lives for the lifetime of the program and gets accessed by various classes! Is that OK?

Comment: @Vahid: I'd still recommend sticking with these patterns.  If this one application only ever has one static building, then encapsulate that behind the factory.  (Maybe the factory internally reads from the config in a static initializer.)  So the rest of the code still just interacts with the factory and both sides of that abstraction are portable and more easily maintained.  Let the use case of the application drive the consuming/orchestrating code, but model the domain after the real-world concepts being used.

Comment: @David Thank you for the insight David. I had a little trouble understanding the BuildingFactory and BuildingRepository parts. Can you guide me to an article that explains this in layman terms or help me understand it.

Comment: @Vahid: There is *a lot* to read/learn on the subject, but the overarching term is "design patterns".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern  The definitive book on the subject should be on the shelf of every programmer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns (though there are numerous others)

Comment: @David I have download the book you suggested. Haven't got enough time to read it though. Actually I'm a structural engineer that is self-teaching himself to be a programmer. So I may have missed a lot of the principles of programming during the learning process. I have written 80% of a rather complicated  structural detailing cad program using a bit non-standard principles like the pattern above. It is working very fast but I know deep in my heart that it is not maintainable. Is there any article regarding the Factory pattern you suggested?

Comment: @Vahid: Google can find many such articles.  One prolific patterns author, for example, might be Martin Fowler.  Don't worry about being self-taught or a novice.  I know many *very experienced* developers who struggle with patterns.  You'll find that you can easily write software without them, it's in the long-term maintainability of that software where you'll find their uses.  Especially if that software is being maintained by a larger team.